# Email not send from a specific user in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I am triggering an email to a user if the a record is marked as submitted, this works only when the record is created by a specific user, same does not happen when another user of same profile creates the record.
No errors as well found when debugged the flow.

kindly let me know what can be wrong here

Both users have same profile and permission set assigned

Comment: same user role? does flow go through same path when you debug it? maybe there's a decision node that evaluates differently. Have you verified it's really not sent, really missing from setup -> email log files? because maybe it was sent but went to spam/junk folder

Answer (score 0):

Adding email id to user solved the issue